# How do I specify "Run with highest privileges" in SchTasks?

Tags: windows-7, task-scheduler

When I use the **GUI** Task Scheduler, I can easily check the "*Run with highest privileges*" checkbox.

I found no such option in the **SchTasks** command line too, however.

Is there a way to do that from the command line?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

That's what the **/RL option** does.

Example: `SCHTASKS /Create /TN "New Task" /SC HOURLY /TR blah.exe /RU username /RP password /RL HIGHEST`

Comment: can we use that for each version of Windows (from XP to 7 or 8, including Windows Server 2008) ?

Comment: Not for Windows XP, according to Microsoft (http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx?mfr=true), also note the "this option is not available" comments for (XP and WinServer 2003) on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Rolf check out my answer for a small script, that will work on both XP/2003 and Vista/2008 (or higher)

Answer (score 7):

`/RL level` Sets the Run Level for the job. Valid values are `LIMITED` and `HIGHEST`. The default is `LIMITED`.

Answer (score 3):

To add to @Skatterbrainz's answer: If you run the same command/script on XP/2003, specifying /RL, SchTasks.exe will fail to create the task.

You can make a script that will work on XP, 2003, Vista, 2008, 7, 2008R2 etc., by pulling the OS version from the registry. A batch script could look like this:

```
setlocal
set runlevel=

REM Get OS version from registry
for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('reg.exe query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v "CurrentVersion"') do set os_ver=%%j

REM Set run level (for Vista or later - version 6)
if /i "%os_ver:~,1%" GEQ "6" set runlevel=/rl HIGHEST

REM Execute SchTasks.exe
schtasks.exe /create /tn "Task Name" /sc ONSTART /TR "C:\Scripts\somescript.cmd" /ru SYSTEM %runlevel%
```