# setting a program to run as admin in a standard account

Tags: windows-7

I am managing a few computers and there is a program on them that must be run as an admin to work. There are multiple standard users and one admin user (me) on the computers. Is there a way to set only that program to run as an administrator without needing to enter in admin credentials every time on a standard account?

Comment: You could hard code a batch file with the administrator username/password to start the application with the run as command.  Obviously that is a really bad idea for security.  What program is the challenge?  LPChip has a good idea.

Comment: This question keeps coming up (and we seem to have a lot of trouble finding good answers).  See [Allow administrator rights to a program running under a limited account](http://superuser.com/q/782090), [Automatically run a batch file as administrator](http://superuser.com/q/788924), [Always run a given program as an administrator in Windows 8.1 without prompt](http://superuser.com/q/664001), [Schedule a task with admin privileges without a user prompt in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/q/770420), and [How do I specify “Run with highest privileges” in SchTasks?](http://superuser.com/q/243605)